# How to get Aliases IP as source IP at destination machine?

Tags: linux, networking, mount, nfs

I have setup where client and server are connected to same switch. 
On server I have created a network bond bond0 between two interfaces e0a and e0b. The bond0 IP is 192.168.1.200. Server has NFS share where client can read and write.

On Client, interface e0b has 192.168.1.34. I have created the aliases on the same interface e0b:2 192.168.1.35, e0b:3 192.168.1.36.

I have mounted nfs share on client using,

```
# mount -t nfs -o clientaddr=192.168.1.34 192.168.1.200:/log_disk1 /mnt/alb1
# mount -t nfs -o clientaddr=192.168.1.35 192.168.1.200:/log_disk1 /mnt/alb2
# mount -t nfs -o clientaddr=192.168.1.36 192.168.1.200:/log_disk1 /mnt/alb3
```

After mounting I am doing reading and writing to the NFS share on client using the opensource traffic generator fio.

```
# cd /mnt/alb1
# fio --name=albBondRD --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=1 --rw=randwrite --bs=4k --direct=0 --size=12G --numjobs=8 --runtime=300 --group_reporting &

# cd /mnt/alb2
# fio --name=alb2RD --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=1 --rw=randwrite --bs=4k --direct=0 --size=12G --numjobs=8 --runtime=300 --group_reporting &

# cd /mnt/alb3
# fio --name=alb3RD --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=1 --rw=randwrite --bs=4k --direct=0 --size=12G --numjobs=8 --runtime=300 --group_reporting &
```

I am checking the "netstat" "ESTABLISHED" output on the server, I am getting connection ESTABLISHED only 192.168.1.34 with this IP.

I am thinking to establish multiple sessions like in traffic generators for example Lanforge.
How can I get the session with connection established with aliases IPs?

Comment: What happens if you mount the directories in a different order (e.g. alb2-alb1-alb3)? Do all directories start using .1.35 then?

Comment: no they will not get mount at all if i change the order of mounting, 1.34 is the IP of interface e0b .